# Two ideals and their quotient rings (inclusion relationship)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**False statement**

Let the ring $R$ and its ideals $I$ and $J$ s.t. $I\subset J$.

$R/J$ is a ideal (or subring)  of  the   $R/I$ ?

Since $R/J$ is not a subset of the $R/I$ (actually $R/J$ is a isomorphic with some quotient ring of the $R/I$, the above statement is surely incorrect.

For example $Q[x]/\langle(x-1) \rangle $ is not a subset of the $Q[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2) \rangle$

(When we taking the $I (= \langle (x-1)(x-2) \rangle)  \subset J(= \langle (x-1) \rangle)  $)

The other example $Z/\langle 2 \rangle $ is not a subset of the $Z /\langle 4 \rangle$
(When we taking the $I (= \langle 4 \rangle)  \subset J(= \langle 2 \rangle)  $)

**Question**

**Let the ring $R$ and its ideal $I$ and $J$ s.t. $I\subset J$**

**Let the $R_I$ be a subring or ideal of $R/I$**

**Then Does $R_I$ exist $s.t.$ isomorphic with the $R/J$ ?**

(I.E. I want to know existence of $R/I$'s subring or ideal who is ismorphic with the $R/J$ )

It looks like a true when we considering the above two examples.(It's just my thoght.)

$Q \times \{0\}(\simeq Q[x]/\langle(x-1) \rangle \simeq Q )$ is a subring or 
ideal of the $Q[x]/\langle(x-1)(x-2) \rangle$ .

$\{ 1,3\}(\simeq Z/\langle 2 \rangle \simeq Z_2) $ is a subring or ideal of the $Z /\langle 4 \rangle$.

**But I'm not sure this is right or not.**

(Cause I couldn't find the other counterexmaples and don't know how to prove. :()

What do you think about that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: If I understood your notations correct, $R_I=\{ 1,3\}$ is not a subring of $Z /\langle 4 \rangle$, becuase $1+1=2\not\in R_I$.

Comment: Yes, you've already understood my notation  correctly! Ah thanks for answering.